# recover data on hard and omiting bad sectors

Tags: data-recovery, file-recovery

I had a hard drive with 4 partitions and one of them has a ext4 filesystem and another 3 partitions have ntfs FS.

I wanted to install new ubuntu on ext4 partition but I formated all my hard drive and now I want to backup all my data on ntfs partitions.
there are lot of solutions that I found but I want a livecd software to do that because of some problems.

Moreover I have some bad sectors and I want to omit them from my hard. is there any livecd softwares that I can use for solve these problems?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You need second hard drive to save an image of your bad disk.
Take a dump from the bad drive first. To skip read errors you need option  conv=noerror .

dd if=/dev/sda of=/path/to/directory/on/other/disk conv=noerror

Then take a tool like photorec and scan the image. It may find some files.
For some types of data you may need other tools.